# Can not retrieve a jpg image using php

Tags: php, oracle, http

I am retrieving a jpg file from an oracle db, and trying to output it with the echo command.  The jpg file is stored as a blob inside the database, and displays properly when I access it from the database.  Here is the relevant code:

```
$query = 'select * from answer where answer_id = :answer_id';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':answer_id', $answer_id);

oci_execute($stmt);


if ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_BOTH)){

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    $mylob =  $row['ANS_PICTURE']->load();
    echo $mylob;

}
```

This sends out an amount of data that is consistent with the size of the file, but the browser is completely unable to interpret it as an image.

Strangely, when I use

```
$fp = fopen('test.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $mylob);
```

I can save the file and it has no trouble displaying the image, even using the browser to open the image through the server.

If I add a file-disposition header and prompt the user to save the image, it still does not display the image when I open it.

So it seems like there is a problem between printing the data and the browser receiving the data, though I have no idea what the problem could be.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for any extra output that might have snuck in before or after your image data.

In particular, check for

- A [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) before your opening `<?php` tag
- Trailing whitespace on your script and any other included scripts. The easiest way to defeat this is to omit the closing `?>` tag or even better, execute `exit;` after echoing your image data.

Lastly, this probably has no effect at all but I believe the correct header name is `Content-Type` (capital "C", capital "T").

Comment: This fixed it, thanks!  Turns out I had some trailing whitespaces that I didn't even think to check.  Got rid of those and added an exit; for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Content-Length header. You should retrieve $mylob_length from database because checking it's every time can be a slowdown:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . $mylob_length);
```